# Function statement/programming on paper in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, subquery, function

i'm sorry for this probably a stupid question, but i have to make a couple of queries for a test, but i do not have access to a decent computer with the right software so basically i can only use pen and paper and have access to internet. 
Assignment > Create a function that changes all the English consonant letters into uppercase and all the English 
vowels into lowercase. (Hints: c CHAR; c > 'a', INSTR). Example: 
funnycase('christmas time') => 'CHRiSTMaS TiMe'

I was thinking more like a programmer and thought that maybe there is a way to do it like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f1 (in_word IN VARCHAR(20)) RETURN VARCHAR (20)
IS answer VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN;
DECLARE CHAR c;
```

So here is where i fail and i need help:

```
FOR char IN in_word .... if char NOT IN ("a","e", "i", "o", "u") THEN UPPERCASE char
Else pass?
```

Another thing is i do not know how to add it to answer

```
Answer add char?
Return answer;
End;
```

I am totally unclear how instr works and I can't understand how to use it without help of a computer. 
I am programming with pen and paper.

Also I wrote another query:

Study how LISTAGG function works. Write a query that lists all the departments ordered by 
department name. Show 
· department name, 
· location, 
· comma-separated list of people in that department ordered by name, 
· average salary compared to company average in %

Only knowing data from there https://courses.cs.ut.ee/MTAT.03.288/2013_fall/uploads/Main/p06_data.txt

```
SELECT dname, loc, LISTAGG(ename, "; ") WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename), 
TRUNC( ( (SUM(sal) OVER () ) / ( SUM(sal) OVER (PARTITION BY dname) ) , 2 ) AS AvgSal
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t1.dname, t1.location, t2.ename, t2.sal FROM Dept t1, EMP t2
WHERE t1.deptno = t2.deptno ) ORDER BY dname;
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm is the function for the first part

Comment: By the way, you don't need to install Oracle to do your homework. Use http://www.sqlfiddle.com